# Unable to get KVM working in Guest OS

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have the CPU AMD Ryzen 2700x.

In the BIOS, I have enabled SVM

If I run `lscpu` on the host OS, I get:

```
Virtualisation: AMD-V
```

If I run `sudo kvm-ok` on the host OS, I get:

```
INFO: /dev/kvm exists 
KVM acceleration can be used
```

If I run `lscpu` on the guest OS, I get:

```
Hpervisor version: KVM
Virtualisation: full
```

If I run `sudo kvm-ok` on the host OS, I get:

```
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

In VirtualBox, I have `Enabled VT-x/AMD-V` ticked.

I have even tried setting the CPU to 1 core, but KVM does not seem to work in the guest os, but seems fine in the host os.

Both the host and guest OS are Ubuntu 18.04.

Guest additions seems to be installed.

Virtualbox version is 5.2.42.

How do I get KVM working in the guest OS?

Comment: What you want is calld *nested virtualization*, and I believe it is not supported [before VirtualBox 6](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/relnotes/nested-virt-support.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.